Suddenly started getting Illegal invocation JS errors in my iframe embedded YouTube videos
I am developing a .net8 Blazor app in Visual Studio 2022 and on some of the pages it has YouTube videos embedded. This week I have suddenly started getting a javascript error every time I load a page that has a video embedded in it. However, nothing has been changed on these pages, and I have even rolled back to previous known good code versions and it's still happening with these, so I can't see it being something I have changed in my code.
This is the error I am seeing:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Illegal invocation
Stack trace:
 >  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493)))), <anonymous>:1:175)
 >    at es (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493)))), <anonymous>:1:227)
 >    at P.eval [as C] (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:52418)
 >    at Js (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:33949)
 >    at CE (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:15108)
 >    at x (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:19064)
 >    at aO (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:27433)
 >    at new P (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:22373)
 >    at yu.AIi_ (eval at <anonymous> (:2:493), <anonymous>:3820:53493)
 >    at kt (eval at <anonymous> (https://www.google.com/js/th/Z8rftVTuhfnBSIgQienuNH7YHhJzz6y51ExA7Rj3D5U.js:2:493), <anonymous>:3219:4877)
 >    at LE (eval at <anonymous> (https://www.google.com/js/th/Z8rftVTuhfnBSIgQienuNH7YHhJzz6y51ExA7Rj3D5U.js:2:493), <anonymous>:3219:25079)
 >    at new Cj (https://www.youtube.com/s/player/0ccfa671/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js:861:140)
 >    at Gva (https://www.youtube.com/s/player/0ccfa671/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js:2697:41)
 >    at https://www.youtube.com/s/player/0ccfa671/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js:2695:99
 >    at f (https://www.youtube.com/s/player/0ccfa671/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js:2093:134)
 >    at https://www.youtube.com/s/player/0ccfa671/player_ias.vflset/en_US/base.js:1667:65

To me it looks like something has changed recently in the YouTube/Google JS files that is causing the crash.
I am not doing anything special when I am embedding the video. I just right click on the video on youtube, and click on 'copy embed code' and paste it into my html. Here is an example:
<iframe width="929" height="619" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sdUUx5FdySs" title="Kiwi!" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>

I have also tested to see if it was a specific parameter that was causing the issue, but even if I simply do this:
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sdUUx5FdySs"></iframe>

The problem is still happening. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? Its  a real pain because every time it happens it causes my debugger to break.
